# if-statement not working with creating and object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

working on a project to create a website to buy tickects, and on the site you need to fill in every box for the code to create an object and store that in an array if not filled inn it will clear all the input boxes and show an error message. but even with some of the requirements failing it still pushes to the array.

JS code:
'''

```
const billett = [];
function test() {


    let valgtFilm = document.getElementById("film").value;
    let antall = document.getElementById("antall").value;
    let fornavn = document.getElementById("forNavn").value;
    let etternavn = document.getElementById("etterNavn").value;
    let telefon = document.getElementById("telefornr").value;
    let epost = document.getElementById("epost").value;
    let tall = Number(antall);
    let telefonnr = Number(telefon);

    let ut = "<table><tr>" +
        "<th>Film</th><th>antall</th><th>Navn</th><th>Etternavn</th><th>Telefonnr</th><th>Epost</th>" +
        "</tr>";

    const nyBillett = {
        film: valgtFilm,
        antall: tall,
        navn: fornavn,
        etternavn: etternavn,
        tlf: telefonnr,
        epost: epost,
    }

    if (valgtFilm === "non") {
        document.getElementById("valgterr").innerHTML = "Velg en film";

    }
    if (tall <= 0) {
        document.getElementById("antallerr").innerHTML = "Skriv inn antall biletter";
    }
    if (fornavn === "") {
        document.getElementById("forNavnerr").innerHTML = "Skriv inn fornavnet ditt";
    }
    if (etternavn === "") {
        document.getElementById("etterNavnerr").innerHTML = "Skriv inn etternavnet ditt";
    }
    if (isNaN(telefonnr) || telefon === "") {
        document.getElementById("tlferr").innerHTML = "Skriv inn telefon nummeret ditt";
    }
    if (epost === "") {
        document.getElementById("eposterr").innerHTML = "Skriv inn en epost";
    }
    else {

        billett.push(nyBillett);
        for (let b of billett){

            ut += "<tr>";
            ut += "<td>" + b.film + "</td><td>" + b.antall + "</td><td>" + b.navn + "</td><td>" + b.etternavn + "</td><td>" + b.tlf + "</td><td>" + b.epost + "</td>";
            ut += "</tr>";

            document.getElementById("bestilt").innerHTML = ut;

            //fjerner verdier
            document.getElementById("film").value = 'Velg film her';
            document.getElementById("antall").value = "";
            document.getElementById("forNavn").value = "";
            document.getElementById("etterNavn").value = "";
            document.getElementById("telefornr").value = "";
            document.getElementById("epost").value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: Most of your `if` statements need to be `else if`

Comment: Not `else if` - because you want to handle multiple cases of bad input. Create a flag before all the `if` statements: `let success = true;` Then inside each `if` block add `success = false;`. Lastly, change `else {` to `if (success) {`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp; `else if`` forces code execution across each error check, one by one.

Comment: @JMP if i do else if instead of if the code will do just the first error, and i need it to display every error at onces

Comment: @johnnymopp how do i implement it ? i did `let success = true;
        if (epost === "") { on every if and added `success = false;`after ever innerHTML error message and changed the `else` to `if (success) {`

Comment: @JMP With `else if`, once one block is executed the rest are ignored. So, for example, if `fornavn === ""` AND `etternavn === ""` and you are using `else if` - only the first error msg is printed but we want ALL error messages printed.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set a flag for success. When any of the conditions fail, change the success flag to fail, too. Then at the end only add to the table if the success flag is true.

```
let success = true;
if (valgtFilm === "non") {
    document.getElementById("valgterr").innerHTML = "Velg en film";
    success = false;
}
if (tall <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("antallerr").innerHTML = "Skriv inn antall biletter";
    success = false;
}
if (fornavn === "") {
    document.getElementById("forNavnerr").innerHTML = "Skriv inn fornavnet ditt";
    success = false;
}
// etc......

// If, at this point success is true, none of the conditions failed
if (success) {
    billett.push(nyBillett);
    for (let b of billett){
        // code removed for brevity
    }
}
```